# Android Service exits leaving imp. data open

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentfilter

I am facing a grave problem. Inside a `service` I am opening Wifi connection and closing it after my task completes. Since, a `service` exits at any point i face a problem wherein the connection opens and remains open.

Is there a way i can handle this as i am using `START_STICKY` or i will have to handle it programmatically only?

**EDIT** : Can i share my intent information across couple of receivers (`BroadcastReceiver`). For example, I will write another receiver for action `android.net.wifi.wifi_state_changed` and my existing receiver is for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. 
IF that can be achieved i can do something about it.

**EDIT2** : My code is as follows:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CallReceiver";
    private static final String CALL_ACTION = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent callIntent)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Inside onReceive of CallReceiver----------------");


        if (callIntent.getAction().equals(CALL_ACTION))
        {

            try
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                context.startService(myIntent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"----------------Exception occured while starting service----------------");
            }
        }
    }
}


public class MyService extends Service {
    private Context context;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyService";
    private Thread thread = null;

    public MyService() 
    {
        super();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Inside Email Service constructor----------------");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent myIntent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Email Service Command Started----------------");
        try
        {
            context = getApplicationContext();
            if(thread == null || !thread.isAlive())
            {
                thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable("Email Sender", myIntent));
                thread.start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                  "----------------Exception occured in Email Service onStartCommand----------------");
        }
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        String name;
        Intent myIntent;

        public MyRunnable(String name, Intent myIntent) {
            this.name = name;
            this.myIntent = myIntent;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                doStuff(emailIntent);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }

    private void doStuff(Intent emailIntent) throws InterruptedException, Exception
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            boolean isWifiConnection = false;

            try
            {
                // Check if WiFi connection is available ,if yes try opening it;
                // Attempt to open WiFi connection
                isWifiConnection = Utility.isEnableWifiSuccessful(getApplicationContext());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Wifi conn enabled = " + isWifiConnection
                               + "----------------");

                if (isWifiConnection)
                {
                    // Do more stuff
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Code never reaches here !! Somehow, the service stops and by
                // the time the service stops,
                // WiFi has been enabled
                try
                {
                    if (isWifiConnection)
                    {
                        Utility.isDisableWifiSuccessful(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                          "----------------Error occured while closing network connections----------------");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Context is null----------------");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, if i have another receiver as NetworkReceiver

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String ACTION = "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "NetworkReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent networkIntent)
    {
        if(networkIntent.getAction().equals(ACTION))
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "----------------Inside Network Receiver----------------");
            //Do something which will keep track who has opened the WiFi connection
        }
    }
}
```

then can `myIntent` and `networkIntent` share information and can `MySerivce` read that information.

Any help would be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Service exits when the memory is too low, since you are already using START_STICKY, the service will be restarted once the memory resources are available. I beleive you might need to check if the connection is opened and you are done with the task, then you have stop the service by using stopSelf().

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: The problem which can arise is if the service exits leaving the connection open and someone (user/application) closes it or vice -versa i am in a soup.